# How to map values of one dataframe to asecond dataframes of different length using PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock

i have daily stock data in a dataframe as below:

```
 Date       Open      High       Low     Close    Volume    Change    Week_Number    
1   2018-03-19  0.479304  0.479304  0.479304  0.479304    2050 -0.040000           12             
2   2018-03-20  0.479304  0.479304  0.479304  0.479304       0  0.000000           12              
3   2018-03-21  0.499275  0.499275  0.489290  0.489290   28265  0.020833           12             
4   2018-03-22  0.489290  0.489290  0.489290  0.489290      75  0.000000           12               
5   2018-03-23  0.489290  0.489290  0.489290  0.489290       0  0.000000           12               
6   2018-03-26  0.489290  0.489290  0.479304  0.479304    7020 -0.020408           13               
7   2018-03-27  0.479304  0.479304  0.479304  0.479304       0  0.000000           13               
8   2018-03-28  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312    2861 -0.010417           13               
9   2018-03-29  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312       0  0.000000           13               
10  2018-03-30  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312       0  0.000000           13               
11  2018-04-02  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312       0  0.000000           14
```

I then take this data and convert it to weekly stock data and perform a calculation (weekly_Final) as per below

```
     Open      High       Low     Close   Volume    Change  Weekly_Final
Year Week_Number                                                                         
2018 12           0.479304  0.499275  0.479304  0.489290    30390       NaN             2
     13           0.489290  0.489290  0.474312  0.474312     9881 -0.030612             1
     14           0.474312  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312        0  0.000000             0
     15           0.474312  0.474312  0.449348  0.459333    40277 -0.031579             3
     16           0.459333  0.469319  0.459333  0.469319    10000  0.021739             0
```

what i now need to do is take the weekly final column and map the values in weekly final to the corresponding weekly_Number in the daily dataframe to produce the following:

```
    Date       Open      High       Low     Close    Volume    Change    Week_Number   Weekly_Final 
1   2018-03-19  0.479304  0.479304  0.479304  0.479304    2050 -0.040000           12             2
2   2018-03-20  0.479304  0.479304  0.479304  0.479304       0  0.000000           12             2 
3   2018-03-21  0.499275  0.499275  0.489290  0.489290   28265  0.020833           12             2
4   2018-03-22  0.489290  0.489290  0.489290  0.489290      75  0.000000           12             2  
5   2018-03-23  0.489290  0.489290  0.489290  0.489290       0  0.000000           12             2  
6   2018-03-26  0.489290  0.489290  0.479304  0.479304    7020 -0.020408           13             1  
7   2018-03-27  0.479304  0.479304  0.479304  0.479304       0  0.000000           13             1  
8   2018-03-28  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312    2861 -0.010417           13             1  
9   2018-03-29  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312       0  0.000000           13             1  
10  2018-03-30  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312       0  0.000000           13             1  
11  2018-04-02  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312  0.474312       0  0.000000           14             0
```

I'm relatively novice with python/ pandas and so far my attempts to achieve this have failed miserably.

I have tried to use `pd.np.where` statements but I am continually met with errors relating to the differing data frame sizes.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this.

```
pd.merge(left=daily_stock_data, right=weekly_stock_data[['Week_Number', 'Weekly_Final']], how="inner", on="Week_Number")
```

Check out [pandas.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html) for more

Comment: that makes sense, thank you for pointing that function out to me. i have run into an issue trying to use it however. im getting "KeyError: 'Week_Number' " as the error. i assume his means that it cant find the colun named Week_number.

i created the weekly data from the daily data by using:

weekly_data = daily_data.groupby(['Year', 'Week_Number']).agg(
            {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last', 'Volume': 'sum'})

im not sure if this would impact the ability to reference the week number as the column name for the merge

Comment: @harrisonhodge The columns used to group the dataframe will be converted into indices, unless explicitly specified not to. So pass 'as_index=False' in groupby function. weekly_data = daily_data.groupby(['Year', 'Week_Number'], as_index=False).agg( {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last', 'Volume': 'sum'})

Comment: @harrisonhodge Glad I could help! Please consider marking this answer as accepted if your problem is solved.